# .res files don't include to exe file, but .rs files links succesfully

Tags: windows, winapi, cmake, ninja

I never worked with Win-specific programming and today I've decided to figure out this question. I use Cmake and Ninja and to include a resource file, I use the following line in the Cmake config:

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/windows/test.res" ${APP_SOURCE_FILES} )
```

And when I open properties of my app using context menu I don't see any meta data or icon. These ones are described in the .res file, which I try to include.
But if I use non-compiled resource file everything works (.rs). How should I link a .res file with my app?

For compilling res files I use windres by msys2

Comment: The output of [compiling an .rc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/resource-compiler) produces a binary representation of the resource definition statements. That file needs to be passed to the linker (as you've [already discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74212164/1889329)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I am not only winapi-beginner. I am also a cmake beginner. When a path is added to `add_executable` Cmake tries to compile a file with the specified path to a .obj file. But because a .res file has been compiled, cmake just does nothing. In this case, I have to add .res file to the link flags instead. Google, thank you. You're the best :)